# Check if input has the same value React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, formik

**Question**:

How to prevent submit if value hasn't changed? 
I tried to do this using `useState`.

**Snippet:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik'

const Search = () => {

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = q => {
    window.location.href = `https://for-example.com/search?q=${q}`
  }

  return (
    <Formik onSubmit={({q}, {setSubmitting}) => {
      setSubmitting(false)
      setSearchValue(q) // <===
      return q !== searchValue && handleSubmit(q) // <===
    }} initialValues={{q: ''}} render={() => (
      <Form>
        <Field name='q' />
      </Form>
    )}/>
  )
}
```

**P.S.** This works but I think it's not worth creating `useState` for this simple task. Can I check the search value in another way?

Comment: This is the React way of doing things

Comment: @Andrew, yeah, it might be strange to ask this question but I will wait for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're changing window location in your `handleSubmit` function, you don't need to worry about future states. You can use `dirty` prop passed in render prop, something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik'

const Search = () => {

  const handleSubmit = q => {
    window.location.href = `https://for-example.com/search?q=${q}`
  }

  return (
    <Formik onSubmit={({q}, {setSubmitting}) => {
      setSubmitting(false)
      handleSubmit(q)
    }} initialValues={{q: ''}} render={({ dirty, handleSubmit, isSubmitting }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field name='q' />
        <button type="submit" disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    )}/>
  )
}
```

If you're not changing location on submit, or for any other reason same form can be submitted multiple times (with different values), than you need `state` in some form, either local like you did here, or global.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! window.location.href was actually written as an example. Generally I agree with you answer!

Comment: Hi! I'm glad it helped.